# Attaching two manifolds along their boundary

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have a question about a proof in John Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds.*

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are two topological $n$-manifolds with nonempty boundary (for reference, the definition I am using is: $M$ and $N$ are second countable Hausdorff spaces such that each point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to either an open set in $\mathbf{R}^n$ or an open set in $\mathbf{H}^n = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbf{R}^n: x_n \geq 0\}$). If $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ denote the manifold boundaries of $M$ and $N$, suppose $h: \partial N \to \partial M$ is a homeomorphism. We may attach $M$ and $N$ along their boundaries by forming the adjuction space

$$ M \cup_h N = \frac{M \sqcup N}{\sim}$$

where $\sim$ is the relation generated by identifying $x\in \partial N$ with $h(x)$. The theorem is:

> With $M$, $N$, and $h$ as above, $M \cup_h N$ is an $n$-manifold (without boundary).

The proof first proceeds to show that each point of the adjuction space has a euclidean neighborhood. If $q: M \sqcup N \to M \cup_h N$ denotes the quotient map, then Lee puts $S=q(\operatorname{Int} M \cup \operatorname{Int} N)$ (where $\operatorname{Int}$ denotes the manifold interior) and shows that each point of $M \cup_h N -S$ has a euclidean neighborhood. I am OK with this argument.

Now, I quote:

> Suppose $s\in S$, and let $y \in \partial N$ and $x=h(y) \in \partial M$ be two points in the fiber $q^{-1}(s)$. We can choose coordinate charts $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ and $(V, \psi)$ for $N$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, and let $\hat{U}=\phi(U)$, $\hat{V} = \psi(V) \subseteq \mathbf{H}^n$. It is useful in this proof to identify $\mathbf{H}^n$ with $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$ with $\mathbf{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbf{R}$. By shrinking $U$ and $V$ if necessary, we may assume $h(V \cap \partial N) = U \cap \partial M$, and that $\hat{U} = U_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$ and $\hat{V} = V_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and some open subsets $U_0,V_0 \subseteq \mathbf{R}^{n-1}$.

My question: How does one choose the coordinate domains $U$ and $V$ to satisfy these two conditions simultaneously? I know how to choose $U$ and $V$ such that $h(V \cap \partial N) = U \cap \partial M$, and I know how to choose $U$ and $V$ such that their images under the coordinate maps are equal to sets of the form $U_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$ and $V_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$, but I don't know how to pick $U$ and $V$ such that both of these conditions are satisfied at the same time.

EDIT: Let me be a bit more specific. We are to choose the coordinate domains (by shrinking if necessary) to satsify the following two conditions simultaneously:

(a) $h(V \cap \partial N) = U \cap \partial M$,

(b) $\hat{U} = U_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$ and $\hat{V} = V_0 \times [0,\epsilon)$.

Now, assuming that I have adjusted $U$ and $V$ to satisfy (a), then I may adjust them further to satisfy (b). But then how do I know that $U$ and $V$ still satisfy (a)? I can be more specific by what I mean by "adjust" if neeeded.

Am I misreading the proof, or am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT 6/17/19:** Another reader recently pointed out that the argument I sketched below is not appropriate for this place in the book, since it uses properties of compactness that are not introduced until Chapter 4. I'll leave my original answer here for those who are curious; but a much better solution is to just abandon the idea of arranging for the images of the coordinate maps to be product open sets, because that was not really needed anyway. I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

**Original Answer:**

Here's a way to see it.  Choose charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, and let  $U_1 = U\cap \partial M$ (which is a  neighborhood of $x$ in $\partial M$) and   $V_1 = V\cap \partial N$ (a neighborhood of $y$ in $\partial N$).  After shrinking $U$ if necessary, we may assume that $h(U_1)\subset V_1$. (Because $U_1\cap h^{-1}(V_1)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in the subspace topology $\partial M$ inherits from $M$, there is an open subset $\widetilde U\subset M$ such that $U_1\cap h^{-1}(V_1) = \widetilde U\cap\partial M$.  Replacing $U$ by $U\cap \widetilde U$ does the trick.)   Let $U_0\subset U_1$ be a neighborhood of $x$ that's precompact in $U_1$, and let $V_0 = h(U_0)\subset V_1$, a precompact neighborhood of $y$ in $V_1$.

Now let $\widehat U=\varphi(U)$, $\widehat V=\psi(V)$, considered as subsets of $\mathbb H^n  = \mathbb R^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$.  Since $\varphi(\overline {U_0})$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}\times \{0\}$,  there is some $\varepsilon_1>0$ such that $\varphi(\overline {U_0})\times[0,\varepsilon_1)\subset \widehat U$.  Similarly, there's $\varepsilon_2>0$ such that $\psi(\overline {V_0})\times[0,\varepsilon_2)\subset \widehat V$.  Now just take $\varepsilon = \min(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2)$, and replace $U$ by $\varphi^{-1}\big(\varphi(U_0)\times[0,\varepsilon)\big)$ and $V$ by $\psi^{-1}\big(\psi(V_0)\times[0,\varepsilon)\big)$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the response Dr. Lee. One more quick question and then I've got it: Why does compactness of $\phi( \overline{U}_0)$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n-1} \times \{ 0\}$ imply the existence of $\epsilon_1$?

Comment: Oh, scratch that last question. I see why!

Comment: Since the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^{n-1}\times[0,\infty)$ is the same as the product topology, for each $p\in\varphi(\overline{U_0})$ there exist a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $U_1$ and an $\varepsilon_p>0$ such that $U_p\times [0,\varepsilon_p)\subset \widehat U$. By compactness, finitely many sets $U_{p_1},\dots,U_{p_k}$ cover $\varphi(\overline{U_0})$, and we can take $\varepsilon_1 = \min(\varepsilon_{p_1},\dots,\varepsilon_{p_k})$.

Comment: Hi, Jack :) Don't you just hate having to come up with solutions of your own problems?

Comment: Hi Ted -- I mostly ignore it when people ask for solutions to the problems, because I think they'll learn more by grappling with them on their own, or with help from other learners.  But when they find my explanations in the book unclear, I do feel a bit of an obligation to try to help...

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're worried about having the $\epsilon$'s be the same? You can rescale by a linear map in the $x_n$ coordinate.

OK, if the first condition no longer holds, shrink either $U_0$ or $V_0$ to make it hold.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not my issue. I will edit the question so that it's more clear.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your second comment? I'm not immediately seeing how I can make $U$ and $V$ satisfy the first condition by shrinking $U_0$ and $V_0$.

Comment: Remember that $U_0\times\{0\}=\phi(U\cap\partial M)$, etc. So we're just going to rig it so that $\phi\circ h\circ \psi^{-1}$ carries $V_0$ to $U_0$.

Comment: I apologize for prodding for more details, but I still am not seeing how to choose the correct $U$ and $V$ based off of shrinking $U_0$ and $V_0$. I understand the rest of the proof, it's just this small technicality that is giving me trouble. It's an intuitive proof; essentially what we are trying to do is align the boundaries of $M$ and $N$ so that we can define a map $U \sqcup V \to \mathbf{R}^n$ that passes to the quotient (giving us our coordinate map of $s$). Continued...

Comment: Assuming $U$ and $V$ have been selected to satisfy the two requirements, we write $\phi=(\phi_0,\phi_1)$ and $\psi=(\psi_0,\psi_1)$ and note that the first two coordinate functions $\phi_0$ and $\psi_0$ provide homeomorphisms $U \cap \partial M \to U_0$ and $V \cap \partial N \to V_0$, resepectively. Then $(\phi_0 | U \cap \partial M) \circ h \circ (\psi_0| V \cap \partial N)^{-1}$ is the map you mentioned in your last comment mapping $V_0$ homeomorphically onto $U_0$.

Comment: Maybe I'm being obtuse, but once we have the right $U_0$ and $V_0$, can't we take the new $\tilde U=\phi^{-1}(U_0\times [0,\epsilon))$, etc.?

Comment: Then the new $\tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{V}$ satisfy $h(\tilde{V} \cap \partial N) = \tilde{U} \cap \partial M$?

Comment: Absitively, because we picked $U_0$ and $V_0$ to guarantee this.

Comment: OK, but that's my problem. How did you choose $U_0$ and $V_0$ so that $\tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{V}$ satisfied that condition?